# Get 'Niederlassungserlaubnis' after 33 months of Blue Card without A1

Tags: blue-card, pr

I being in Berlin, for nearly 44 months with Blue card, and I'm planning to apply for 'Niederlassungserlaubnis' before my blue card renewal.
The only document I'm missing is Deutsch A1 certificate. I can introduce my self and my family in Deutsch. Other than that my Deutsch is really bad.
Will this be a problem? What kind of interview will I have? What kind of question will they ask?
(I'm sorry that I failed to learn proper Deutsch, but I had to work 40 hours every week. This is not an excuse, but just a piece of information).
Thank you.

Comment: Level A1 tests listening, reading, writing and speaking skills at a pretty basic level. Have you tried searching online for example tests? Eg https://learngerman.dw.com/en/placement-test-a1/l-36696748

Answer (score 1):

A1 is fairly basic German.  [This page](https://www.expath.de/level-a1-2/) is one description of the sorts of things you would be expected to be able to do.  An excerpt:

> - Referring to items without naming them (den, die, das, mir, dir, ihm, ihr, etc.)
> - Asking about items and identifying specific items (welche, diese, etc.)
> - Expressing belonging (gehören)
> - Using accusative pronouns (mich, dich, etc.)
> - Reading and writing invitations
> - Talking about holidays in Germany
> - Writing formal letters

You absolutely need to achieve this level of fluency in order to obtain the *Niederlassungserlaubnis*.

The option to have it assessed at interview is really for those people who are already fluent (there are quite a few German-speaking communities outside the EU), and who don't want to bother with the exam.  I would not expect the official to give you the benefit of the doubt if you are borderline for A1.

Your options:

- If you think your German is good enough, just take an exam and get the certificate (there are a number of online tests to determine your approximate level).
- Enroll on an intensive course to learn to A1 level (and get the certificate).
- Go to the interview anyway and hope!